# Tensorboard on Windows: 404 _traceDataUrl error

Tags: tensorboard

On Windows when I execute:

c:\python35\scripts\tensorboard --logdir=C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\dev\Deadpool\Tensorflow-SegNet\logs

and I web browse to http://localhost:6006 the first time I am redirected to http://localhost:6006/[[_traceDataUrl]] and I get the command prompt messages:

```
W0913 14:32:25.401402 Reloader tf_logging.py:86] Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
W0913 14:32:25.417002 Reloader tf_logging.py:86] Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event.
W0913 14:32:36.446222 Thread-2 application.py:241] path /[[_traceDataUrl]] not found, sending 404
```

When I try  http://localhost:6006 again, TensorBoard takes a long time presents the 404 message again but this time displays a blank web page.

Logs directory:

```
checkpoint
events.out.tfevents.1504911606.LTIIP82
events.out.tfevents.1504912739.LTIIP82
model.ckpt-194000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-194000.index
model.ckpt-194000.meta
```

Why am I getting redirected and 404ed?

Comment: Now the problem has mysteriously gone away.  But I can't delete this question until it happens again.  So I'll leave it open.  Please don't downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

i'am having the exact same error. Maybe it is because of [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7856) issue. So try to Change the env-variable to --logdir=foo:C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\dev\Deadpool\Tensorflow-SegNet\logs.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you try to access the webpage with IE? Apparently IE is not supported by Tensorboard yet(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9372). Maybe use another Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error before, and found that it was due to internet setting problem.

On Internet Explorer, Go to **Tools** -> **Internet Options** -> **Connections**, click **LAN settings**, and then click **Automatic detect settings**.